# Is (wayland's) libinput something new, i.e., not related to X.Org server?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, wayland

Having read http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/ which states

> libinput is a library to handle input devices in Wayland compositors
>   and to provide a generic X.Org input driver. It provides device
>   detection, device handling, input device event processing and
>   abstraction so minimize the amount of custom input code compositors
>   need to provide the common set of functionality that users expect.

I am confused. I very much hope that the above means libinput is something new, which should mean that nothing of this horrible keyboard layout settings related to X.Org will be carried over to X.Org.

I am confused by the mentioning of X.Org as "X.Org input driver"?
Does this mean rather

a) that the something from X.Org, i.e. an input driver, is brought to Wayland or

b) that Wayland (or libinput) will provide some backward support, so that it would be able to forward input events to a X.Org server running as a client inside of Wayland?

A good way to know this, would be to know how keyboard layouts are implemented in Wayland (I hope very much **not** as overly complicated as in X.Org)

Disclaimer/Update:
Since there was a down-vote. This question should not imply that "being related to X.Org server" is negative. It should simply help out to understand where to put this library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, libinput is something new that started as a part of the wayland project to be used instead of the x11 input drivers (like xorg-evdev and xorg-synaptics and xorg-wacom and so on and so forth).

In answer to your a/b scenario, it would be b, that is that libinput is not dependent on wayland and thus can run on other display servers (like X or Mir) as well.

Comment: this answer helps me much. Considering that one of the reasons that made Wayland attractive to me has been the input is much more separated (i.e. in no keyboard logging in between applications as possible within a X.org session).

Comment: @humanityANDpeace While I might be a bit late here with this, the keyboard logging between applications (e.g. one application being able to read the keyboard input to another) is caused by the display server, not the input drivers in this case, so you still have plenty of reason to use Wayland if that is why you want it.

You'll have to look more deeply into the benefits of using libinput over evdev, but they might be minimal if you're running X anyways. (one sure benefit though is libinput's monolithic structure, trying to support as many HIDs as possible in just one driver)